# Work in the US with H4 visa

Tags: usa, working-visas, eu, legal

I have H4 visa to the US, but I would like to keep my job and work remotely to a European company and pay my tax in a European country. If there any possibility to 'cheat' with the US law which says "no work is permitted in US land, however it is remote for a non-us company"? What if I work in my home country on paper and get my salary to a domestic (EU) bank account? Is it possible or expected that IRS will check my account as well?

Answer (score 1):

> If there any possibility to 'cheat' with the US law which says "no work is permitted in US land, however it is remote for a non-us company"?

Of course.

> What if I work in my home country on paper and get my salary to a domestic (EU) bank account? Is it possible or expected that IRS will check my account as well?

Of course. Not only the IRS, also ICE (the USCIS law enforcement arm).

You can get a prison sentence for the tax evasion, and deportation after that.

But yes, it's possible if you're willing to bear the consequences and a constant fear that even if you haven't been caught **yet**, it only takes a single disgruntled friend/ex/neighbor to remedy the situation and have all your US immigration privileges revoked and you deported.